# Quiero acceder al valor de un diccionario que esta dentro de un dataframe y modificar la columna del dataframe con ese valor

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, diccionarios

Tengo un dataframe que en una de sus columnas tiene como tipo de dato diccionarios:
[image: Columna antes del bucle]

Solo necesito el string de la clave "date".
Como puedo solo dejar ese valor?

He usado bucles para obtener el resultado pero no me parece una manera adecuada de hacerlo:

```
lista_fecha = []
for reg in fechas_usuarios['registered']:
    lista_fecha.append(reg["date"])

fechas_usuarios['registered'] = lista_fecha
```

Resultado:

[image: Columna después del bucle]

Alguna idea de como hacerlo de otra manera?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma simple y eficiente es usar [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) junto a [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
import operator
import pandas as pd


fechas_usuarios = pd.DataFrame(
    {"registered": [
        {"date": "2002-07-14", "age": 21},
        {"date": "2007-11-07", "age": 15},
        {"date": "2009-02-20", "age": 14}]})

fechas_usuarios["registered"] = fechas_usuarios["registered"].apply(operator.itemgetter("date"))
```

Hay otras posibilidades, como usar una función lambda junto a `pandas.Series.apply` (aunque es mas ineficiente que `itemgetter`):

```
fechas_usuarios["registered"] = fechas_usuarios["registered"].apply(lambda reg: reg["date"])
```

O también podemos usar [compresión de listas](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para generar los nuevos valores de la columna, que no dista mucho de tu aproximación pero es una forma mucho mas eficiente de generar la lista:

```
fechas_usuarios["registered"] = [reg["date"] for reg in fechas_usuarios["registered"]]
```

---

Una pequeña observación, con respecto a tu código. En Python, siempre que requieras iterar sobre algo con un `for`, usa preferentemente `for item in iterable` en vez de `for indice in range(len(iterable))` + indizado, a no ser que exista una razón que lo justifique.

Aparte de ser considerablemente mas legible, es mas eficiente. Por ejemplo, en tu caso:

```
lista_fecha = []
for reg in fechas_usuarios['registered']:
    lista_fecha.append(reg["date"])

fechas_usuarios['registered'] = lista_fecha
```

Comment: Que útil, gracias! me ayudó

Comment: Gracias por su observación! lo tendré en cuenta